# ImageView don't want to appear after it's been hidden by setAlpha()

Tags: android, transparency, imageview, shapes

I have a shape defined as a drawable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#0075b5"/>
    <size android:height="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

and I use this shape in an ImageView as source:

```xml
<ImageView android:layout_height="2dp"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:src="@drawable/shape_blue_line"
           android:id="@+id/ptt_blueLineImageView"/>
```

The problem appears when I want to toggle my ImageView:

```java
private void toggleAnimatedLogo() {
        if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 2) {
            animatedLogo.setAlpha(ALHPA_TRANSPARENT);
            blueLine.setAlpha(ALHPA_TRANSPARENT);
        } else {
            animatedLogo.setAlpha(ALHPA_VISIBLE);
            blueLine.setAlpha(ALHPA_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

The result is that on first execution of this method both ImageViews disappears but only the animated one appears on the second. The line since disappearing don't want to show at all. I would like to have a working toggle method.

Answer (score 1):

This might be better accomplished with [View.setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29), use [View.INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) if you still want the ImageView layed-out or [View.Gone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) if you want it to ignore layout.

Comment: I've tried this - it does not work either. (I think they are using setAlpha() underneath)

Comment: moreover, if I use setVisibility() on my animated ImageView it is not hiding at all...

Comment: Did you call [View.clearAnimation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation()).

Comment: I don't want to. I have very specific situation in which my animation should be in proper stage regarding time elapsed since it has been hidden. I would have to call setAnimation() once again. But it is not a problem - a forever-disappering line is an issue.

Comment: Add an [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html) and set the value to transparent.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work either. But I noticed really interesting behaviour. Lineary interpolated animation going to make line invisible works binary - after elapsed time line disappears. But if I set a value near transparency for example 1, where 0 is transparent - the line never disappears, it even doesn't change its color at all. I think shape is an issue... (btw. to be sure, `blueLine` was not animated in first place, only `animatedLogo`)

Comment: At least it was simple and good answer, altough my compiler doesn't seem to be deterministic. :-) Thank you.

Comment: yepp, after editing my xml layout I suppose some code was regenerated and it started to work magically. More on the topic in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So it was really weird behaviour of ImageView. After I made some layout changes in the layout file, which were for sure unrelated (I've checked) to this issue the code started to work. Anyone knows why this happened?

Anyway, I've discovered this after pasting this code above my blueLine in layout xml. The previous line started to work then. After cutting it up again it still works.

```
<View android:layout_height="2dp"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/ptt_blueLineView"
      android:background="#0075b5"/>
```

Eventually, I decided to stay with this new version of line, abandoning shapes...